# Swift passing uninitialized object to block

Tags: objective-c, swift, block

I have been trying to figure out this small thing which was quite easy with Objective C, but could not solve with Swift.

```
var loginViewController: SSLoginViewController

let completion = {
  loginViewController.presentViewController(SSFeedViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}

loginViewController = SSLoginViewController(completion: completion)
```

The intention here is to pass SSLoginViewController a completionBlock to present another view controller. But, the code above gives error.

> Variable 'loginViewController' captured by closure before being
>   initialized.

Delcaring the uninitialized variable as **__block**, the Objective C block would take the changed value from within a block.

It would be something like this in Objective C,

```
__block SSLoginViewController *loginViewController;
dispatch_block_t completion = ^ {
  [loginViewController presentViewController:[[SSFeedViewController alloc] init] animated: YES completion:nil]
};
loginViewController = [[SSLoginViewController alloc] initWithCompletion:completion];
```

How can the similar behavior be achieved with Swift ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be initialized to `nil` (that's what's happening in your Objective-C code anyway; in Objective-C ARC, managed object pointers are initialized to `nil` if not otherwise initialized). This means it will need to be optional. You can use implicitly-unwrapped optional to not have to deal with optional syntax since you know it's only going to be `nil` temporarily.

```
var loginViewController: SSLoginViewController!

let completion = {
  loginViewController.presentViewController(SSFeedViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}

loginViewController = SSLoginViewController(completion: completion)
```

An additional problem, which also exists in your Objective-C code, is that there will likely be a retain cycle. The `SSLoginViewController` object probably stores and thus has a strong reference to the completion block, and the block has a strong reference to the `SSLoginViewController` object. If you know that the completion block will only exists while the `SSLoginViewController` object is alive, then you can have it capture a weak reference to `loginViewController`:

```
var loginViewController: SSLoginViewController!

let completion = { [weak loginViewController] in
  loginViewController.presentViewController(SSFeedViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}

loginViewController = SSLoginViewController(completion: completion)
```